# Regex match for a character without previous character

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String:

`"location-string:location-string:location-C?:\string"`

which I would like to split into the following three Strings:

`location-string` `location-string` `location-C?:\string`

What should the regex expression be when using String.split(regex)?

Basically, I want to split on colon ':' characters except those that are preceded by a '?' character!

Thanks in advance,
PM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use negative lookbehind. It matches the colon which was not preceeded by `?`

```
(?<!\?):
```

Java regex would be,

```
"(?<!\\?):"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aU1nR4/10)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `split()` with limit.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "location-string:location-string:location-C?:\\string";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(":", 3))); 
}
```

O/P :

```
[location-string, location-string, location-C?:\string]
```

Comment: Most regrettably, this is based on the special case (?:) only occurring in a *very* special location (3rd and last). Are you sure this is a good answer considering "I want to split on colon ':' characters except those that are preceded by a '?' character"?

Comment: Double backslash as a comment indicator?

Comment: @laune - yes.. This is very tightly coupled with the given string. I am merely pointing out that this could also be done this way.